# MySQL NOW() returns 00:33:33 01/01/70

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I have the following code in my PHP:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_surveys_completed (score,survey_name,user_id,survey_date)
                VALUES ('".$cr."','Mission Completed (SponsorPay)','".$userid."',NOW())
            ");
```

When the date value NOW() adds to the database it returns not the current date and time but always the same date: "00:33:33 01/01/70".

My question is: How can I fix this, so it will output the date and time?

Comment: That's MySQL `NOW()`, not PHP.

Comment: How do you know what it returns?

Comment: `00:33:33 01/01/70` is `2013` in [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time); I think that should help you with your problem :-)

Comment: on ur mysql query browser check the output of this query `SELECT now();`

Comment: This code uses the deprecated `mysql` extension (migrate away!) and might be vulnerable to SQL injection (use parameterized queries instead!).

Comment: The value 00:33:33 01/01/70 is added to the Date table in my mysql database wp_surveys_completed

Comment: Check the time on the mysql server

Comment: @cbuckley Wow, I have never thought of that! So is it possible the NOW() only returns 2013?

Comment: @SuhelMeman SELECT now(); gives the following output: 2013-02-06 04:55:50

Comment: @Maarten Schermer: nope, it's not. More possible is that you've shown us another query.

Comment: check ur `table structure`.. type of `survey_field` field and `default value` set for this field

Comment: @SuhelMeman type = int(11) default value = none

Comment: change `type` of `survey_field` to `datetime`...

Comment: I figured out that all my date values where Unix Time, so I fixed it by replacing NOW() with UNIX_TIMESTAMP(). Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

change column type of `survey_field`

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` CHANGE `column_name` DATETIME  DEFAULT NULL
```